# Downloading thumbnail images through background service and storing local image paths to database and then displaying in listbox

Tags: c#, wpf, silverlight, windows-phone-7

The scenario I am facing is that i have video's list with thumbnail images at server which i need to display as list in my wp7 application.

So I am getting the Json obects collection for videos having all properties of video like name,albumName,videoUrl,thumbnailUrl. This list I am saving in database. After this I have to download the thumbnails from the corressponding urls and save in isolatedstorage and also save local path to dataabse.

After that binding the list to Listbox from database.

Is this approach correct?? If Yes then I need to run background service for downloading the images then how should i update the database after few images are downloaded and bind the list from database to Listbox and repeat the process.

Answer (score 0):

No, this approach can be improved. If your service has the URI of the thumbnail (eg: thumbnailUrl = "http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/5a058d23828ab74e93dee0b04ed0a7a1?s=128&d=identicon&r=PG"). Then you can use that link inside the Image control.

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding VideoInfos}">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate> 
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Image Source="{Binding ThumbnailUrl}" Width="90"/>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
            </StackPanel> 
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

Assuming that you have a view model with a property `VideoInfos` that is of type `ObservableCollection<VideoInfo>` and that the VideoInfo object has two properties `Name` and `ThumbnailUrl`. Both of these properties can be strings. Get your info from your service and populate this collection. There is no need to put this info into the database unless you don't want to load it again the next time that the user opens the app.

Comment: Hi @Shawn Kendrot first of all thanks for the reply as u have suggessted here is the way i am following currenty. But this approach is having 2 problems first if the count of list is even above 50 its taking much time to load those images and second as u have told in last i dont want to download the images again if user closes the app and open again.

Comment: Downloading these should not take much time IF these are truly thumbnails (small size maybe 100x100). I have an app where I am downloading many 500x500 images and it's fast. One thing to keep in mind is that images are rendered on the UI thread, you can change that by following steps in [this blog](http://windowsteamblog.com/windows_phone/b/wpdev/archive/2012/05/16/listbox-why-art-thou-blanking.aspx). You can also download pictures in the background by using a [BackgroundWorker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc221403(v=VS.95).aspx)